# how to solve 'Expect x to not have duplicates' with scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scipy

i was trying to make curve as follows:

```
    x = all_dat['rcs']
    y = all_dat['Mean_Range']
    xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
    cubic_interploation_model = interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
    y_=cubic_interploation_model(xnew)
    pl.plot(xnew , y_)
```

but i was not getting a plot and end with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\seq_2_final.py", line 268, in <module>
    plot_alldata(df_all,p2)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\seq_2_final.py", line 201, in plot_alldata
    cubic_interploation_model = interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_interpolate.py", line 564, in __init__
    self._spline = make_interp_spline(xx, yy, k=order,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_bsplines.py", line 1295, in make_interp_spline
    raise ValueError("Expect x to not have duplicates")
ValueError: Expect x to not have duplicates

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. You have a duplicate value in x; you need to correct that, either remove it and the corresponding y-value or change it.